# This is a price-demand function question for business calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The price-demand equation for gasoline is 0.4d + 2p = 70.  Where 
p is the price per gallon in dollars and d is the daily demand measured in millions of gallons.

Write the demand d as a function of price.

What would the demand be if it were $6 per gallon

Comment: The question is just asking you to solve for $d$ and evaluate it if $p = 6$. What are you having trouble with, and what have you tried?

Comment: This is "business calculus" and you haven't mastered basic algebra?  I mean to be mean, but if you don't have this down, you are in the wrong class.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Doug. Got an A in algebra but its been 5 years. I guess I was too busy serving this country overseas and have forgotten. Since I am not as smart as you I decided to use a resource. Next time please be helpful instead of passive aggressive. Why else waste your time?

Comment: I tried this ... .4d=70-2p but they want this as a function of price.

Comment: @robertdenam Unfortunately, this question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. Doug's comment should help at least in identifying that this is an algebra question, *not* a calculus one - if you're not sure what the question is asking for or what to try, you really should discuss that with your professor.

Comment: Welcome to the community here on math.stackexchange.  I suggest you read this. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question  Questions that are lacking in context, those that don't show much effort, those that look too much like "please do my homework for me" and those that say "urgent" tend to be treated poorly.    While I appreciate that your math skills may have grown rusty with time, I highly recommend taking some sort of refresher or getting a tutor before proceeding with calculus.

Comment: @DOUGM ok i used a math question (which is what this site is for) and explained that I am having trouble with it. The fact that youve taken all this time to humiliate me and blow the "whistle" blows me away. I honestly dont know how you have all this time. Once I figure out this problem I can use this as a reference. Thats how I learn. I dont need a hall monitor on here trying to throw a rule book at me. Im simply asking for help. Dont like it. Dont visit my question.

Comment: @robertdenam This site tends to react very poorly to questions that are posed without any input by the asker - that is, just saying "here's a problem, I don't know how to do it" is not enough. You ought to have included your *own* work, your *own* background, and what you've tried. I think what Doug is also pointing out (albeit not in the best way) is that if you're struggling with a basic algebra question, that is a massive red flag if you're in a calculus course. In my experience teaching calculus, insufficient algebra background is the top reason for failing the course.

Comment: This isnt a traditional calculus class my friend. Its strictly business and doesnt get too crazy into detail like normal calculus tracks. This class is just for business majors. So some of the price/cost functions I am not too familiar with. Does that make it more clear.

Comment: @robertdenam I'm not going to comment after this, because you seem fully committed to the course. However, I really doubt that you actually understand what you're getting into - the lack of understanding that you have here has nothing to do with price or cost functions, but with a very serious gap in your arithmetic/algebra skills. Not getting "too crazy into detail" is not going to take that issue away. And I say this as someone who has taught a university business calculus course. All I can do is exhort you to go and talk to your professor or advisor about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be put as a comment, but you shouldn't be struggling much with this. This question has a simple solution in which you substitute 6 into $p$.

$0.4d+2(6)=70$

$0.4d = 58$

I cannot give you more than this.

And if you're asking for the demand as a "function of price", isolate the variable d.

**NOTE: $1/5 = 0.2$ and $2/5=0.4$**

$2p = 70-2/5d$

$p = 35-1/5d$

MULTIPLY BY 5 ON BOTH SIDES.

$5p = 175-d$

$d=-5p+175$

If you want to know the "demand d as a function of price", it would be

$f(p)=-5p+175$

Comment: How did you get 5p. I follow you all the way until that. ANd thank you for your positive feedback

Comment: I multiplied both sides by $5/2$. If you like this answer, click the check mark next to it.

Comment: @robertdenam . 
I multiplied both sides by 5/2. If you like this answer, click the check mark next to it.

Comment: ..Ok, once I get to p=35-.2d I then divide both sides by .2 to isolate the variable. That then gives me 175. Im confused on why you are multiplying by 5/2

Comment: @robertdenam To isolate the variable $d$

Comment: I've got this P=35-.2d, I then divide .2d by both sides which gives me. p=175. Just confused on where you got the 5

Comment: @robertdenam 0.2 = 1/5.

Comment: @user296602 Thank you.

Comment: Yea, thanks for all your help but I am too lost. I have a tutor I just dont start until friday and am trying to grasp some stuff. I dont think you're understanding my stumbling block. ...Once I get to  p=35-.2d I get lost. I dont know where you are receiving 5p from . Thats my question.

Comment: @robertdenam What happens when you multiply the equation by 5 on both sides? (Again, this should be an absolutely massive red flag about your background and should be making you take a long hard look at whether you are prepared for a calculus course or not. Taking a refresher in algebra would likely do you a world of good.)

Comment: I will restate the question to make you understand better.

Comment: Thank you. @user296602, This class doesn't allow calculators at all. So I am doing this all with a scrap paper and am trying to figure out why he chose 5.

Comment: are you taking the reciprocal of .2 and using that to multiply? is that what you are getting it from?>

Comment: OK I GOT IT GUYS

Comment: ok thank you everyone